# Invoke-WebRequest Headers

Tags: powershell

Знакомлюсь с командой Invoke-WebRequest

Выполняю команду $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI ya.ru

А затем команду $Response.Headers

Как выбрать информацию из VALUE?

$Response.Headers | Where-Object  или | Select-Object

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:
$Response.Headers.'Cache-Control'